# How to test component watchers with testing-library?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, testing-library, vitest, vue-testing-library

Struggling with `testing-library` and a Vue component with Vuex. This is the component, it has a watcher:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'
  import NProgress from 'nprogress'

  export default {
    computed: mapState(['scraping']),
    watch: {
      scraping: scraping => {
        if (scraping) NProgress.start()
        else NProgress.done()
      }
    },
    created () {
      NProgress.configure({
        speed: 50,
        showSpinner: false,
        trickleSpeed: 50
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

I thought a good test would be to render the component having `scraping` set to `true`, spy on `NProgress` methods, validate it was called, then set `scraping` to `false` and check `NProgress.done()` method was called. However, it seems like the watcher is not being called, not even the initial `start()` method. Only `configure()` is called. What's the best approach to wait for the watcher to be triggered by change?

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import ScrapeProgress from './ScrapeProgress.vue'

const spyConfigure = vi.spyOn(NProgress, 'configure')
const spyStart = vi.spyOn(NProgress, 'start')
const spyDone = vi.spyOn(NProgress, 'done')

const store = createStore({
  state: {
    scraping: true
  },
  mutations: {
    switch (state) {
      state.scraping = !state.scraping
    }
  }
})

describe('ScrapeProgress', async () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    vi.restoreAllMocks()
  })

  it('default view', async () => {
    const el = render(ScrapeProgress, {
      global: {
        plugins: [store]
      }
    })
    expect(spyConfigure).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(spyStart).toHaveBeenCalled(). --------> THIS FAILS!
    store.commit('switch')
    expect(store.state.scraping).toBe(false)
    expect(spyStart).toHaveBeenCalled().
  })
})
```

Comment: This watcher isn't immediate. This means that it won't be triggered for initial scraping value

Comment: @EstusFlask So what would be the solution? Is there any way of triggering it?

Comment: It's triggered when `scraping` is changed. That's the purpose of a watcher

Comment: You are right, this is how it worked as expected:

`await waitFor(() => {expect(spyStart).toHaveBeenCalled()})`

Comment: Yes, that's it. Also nextTick() could be awaited

Comment: Yeah, `nextTick` would also work, but I am using `testing-library` instead of `vue-test-utils`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so following @EstusFlask comment, I changed the test to start with scraping as false in the store, after rendering the component I did a commit to the store to change the scraping value and, very important, use waitFor() for the validation, the watcher is async